# what besides object files and shared dlls is required to create an executable

Tags: c, dll, linker, portable-executable

First I describe what I have done.I am using cygwin on windows 7 64 bit.

I first just created simple program in C say famous hello program.Then I compiled using 'gcc' directly to generate 'hello.exe' .Then I checked the dynamically linked libraries using 'ldd' command and checked their paths.

> $ ldd hello.exe
>
> ntdll.dll => /cygdrive/c/Windows/SYSTEM32/ntdll.dll (0x77a70000)
>
> kernel32.dll => /cygdrive/c/Windows/system32/kernel32.dll (0x77850000)
>
> KERNELBASE.dll => /cygdrive/c/Windows/system32/KERNELBASE.dll (0x7fefdb40000)
>
> cygwin1.dll => /cygdrive/c/Users/vishu/cygwin1.dll (0x180040000)

Then I created object file 'hello.o' instead of generating executable and then used linker to link object files and the shared libraries to create 'hello1.exe'.But when I tried to run it it showed no output .What I am missing?

Note : When I checked using 'file' command for both the files then output are

> $ file hello.exe
>
> hello.exe: PE32+ executable (console) x86-64, for MS Windows
>
> $ file hello1.exe
>
> hello1.exe: PE32+ executable (console) x86-64 (stripped to external PDB), for MS Windows

**Edit for comments** : I do not think that I have written wrong commands as the shared libraries for two executables is the same.I think the type of two executables is different but I do not know what 'stripped to external PDB' means.But as you are asking I will post them below.I copied all dll to same directory as object file hello.o (It is same object file for hello.exe and hello1.exe).

> $ ld -o hello1.exe hello.o ntdll.dll kernel32.dll KERNELBASE.dll cygwin1.dll

Sorry if this is too silly question.

Comment: do you run your program from the command line?

Comment: what happens if you run `./hello.exe ; echo $?`

Comment: it prints hello but for hello1.exe it does not print anything

Comment: should I post symbols obtained using 'nm' command?

Comment: you could try looking at the disassembly of the `main` function (using `gdb` and inside that `disas main`) to see if a call to printf is made. apart from that, I am out of ideas.

Comment: Isn't debugging symbols should be there and I don't know how to use it while using ld command .I just tried using gcc -g.I am new so please help.

Comment: The problem is obviously in the command lines you are entering to compile/link the program.  Please post those lines.

Comment: @user3629249 I have added it please take a look at it